# update content in a view based on database change without page refresh in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

I will simplify the example: A value in my database changes from ON to OFF from time to time. I  load that content in my view. If I make a refresh i obtain the updated value from the database. The question is how to make those changes occur in the view without refreshing? I read that it can be done with ajax and json. Can someone provide a basic example in which a given content in the view changes without refresh using Codeigniter?

Comment: The question is way too broad for StackOverflow.  You need to do some research, write some code, try something out, and come here with a specific question if you get stuck. There are thousands of tutorials... try this one:  http://blog.alysson.net/lang/en-us/tutorial-ajax-com-jquery-e-codeigniter-php-frameworktutorial-ajax-with-jquery-and-codeigniter-php-framework/

Comment: Great tutorial. Solved my problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Learn by code, see

http://runnable.com/UXczcazDrMMiAAGl/how-to-do-ajax-in-codeigniter-for-php

in the form-view.php you will find the  ajax call from the controller, in that example it only shows the time , but in your case you will cal your model and get the "ON" or "OFF" result, you can also change they way your ajax call will be triggered by any event (click, hover...etc) here is the script in code

```
 <script> 
    // using JQUERY's ready method to know when all dom elements are rendered
    $( document ).ready(function () {
      // set an on click on the button
      $("#button").click(function () {
        // get the time if clicked via an ajax get query
        // see the code in the controller time.php
        $.get("/index.php/getTime", function (time) {
          // update the textarea with the time
          $("#text").html("Time on the server is:" + time);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

hope that answer your question